# Why does an animation in SwiftUI jump around

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The goal is to have a Shimmering loading animation. Like facebook and many other apps use.

If I put this in a TabView it works as expected, but if I have the code just in a NavigationView it jump around like in the video. Why does this happen?

If someone could guide me to a solution that would be great!

Video:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/roHm2.jpg

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ShimmeringListView: View {
    
    public var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            ShimmeringCell()
            ShimmeringCell()
        }
    }
}

private struct ShimmeringCell: View {
    @State private var opacity: Double = Constants.minOpacity
    
    public var body: some View {
        cardShimmerAnimation
    }
    
    var cardShimmerAnimation: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                backgroundRectangle
                shimmerRectangles
            }
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 20)
        .padding(.top, 16)
    }
    
    var backgroundRectangle: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(
                LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                        Gradient.Stop(color: .lightGray, location: 0.476),
                        Gradient.Stop(color: .white, location: 0.524)
                    ]),
                    startPoint: .top,
                    endPoint: .bottom))
            .frame(height: 269)
            .cornerRadius(Constants.cornerRadius)
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
    }
    
    var shimmerRectangles: some View {
        VStack {
            oneRectangle
                .frame(height: 28)
                .padding(.trailing, 73)
                .padding(.bottom, 2)
            oneRectangle
                .frame(height: 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 188)
                .padding(.bottom, 2)
            oneRectangle
                .frame(height: 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 130)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            oneRectangle
                .frame(height: 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 188)
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
            oneRectangle
                .frame(height: 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 116)
            Divider()
                .padding(.horizontal, 32)
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
            oneRectangle
                .frame(height: 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 52)
        }
    }
    
    var oneRectangle: some View {
        let baseAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: Constants.duration)
        let repeatedAnimation = baseAnimation.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
        
        return RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.cornerRadius)
            .fill(Color.loadingColor)
            .opacity(opacity)
            .transition(.opacity)
            .padding(.leading, 31)
            .animation(repeatedAnimation)
            .onAppear {
                self.opacity = Constants.maxOpacity
            }
    }
}

private struct Constants {
    static let duration: Double = 0.9
    static let minOpacity: Double = 0.25
    static let maxOpacity: Double = 1.0
    static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 6.0
}
```

Comment: Cool animation free from apple!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need two small changes (see comments inlined in the code):

```
return RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.cornerRadius)
    .fill(Color.loadingColor)
    .opacity(opacity)
    .transition(.opacity)
    .padding(.leading, 31)
    .animation(repeatedAnimation, value: opacity) //<-- Add value: parameter
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //<-- wrap in DispatchQueue.main.async
            self.opacity = Constants.maxOpacity
        }
    }
```

In terms of *why*: For the `animation` modifier, use of the `animation` without the `value` parameter is deprecated and we should expect to use `value:`. For the `DispatchQueue`, my best guess is that the `NavigationView` has an implicit animation attached and we need to start this animation on the next run loop to make sure that it's separate.